# Branching problem of representation of Lie groups and orbit method

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, coadjoint-orbit

Branching problem asks how a restriction of an irreducible representation of $G$ to a subgroup $H$ decomposes. In case of (real) Lie groups, after labeling irreducible representations via highest weights, they are often described as *interlacing* conditions. For example, irreducible representations of $\mathrm{SO}(2n+1)$ (resp. $\mathrm{SO}(2n)$) are in bijection with $n$-tuples of integers $a_1 \geq \cdots \geq a_n \geq 0$ (resp. $b_1 \geq \cdots \geq |b_n|$) and the irreducible representation $\sigma_{\underline{b}}$ of $\mathrm{SO}(2n)$ corresponds to $b_1, \dots, b_n$ occurs in the decomposition of the irreducible representation $\pi_{\underline{a}}$ corresponds to $a_1, \dots, a_n$ if and only if

$$
a_1 \geq b_1 \geq a_2 \geq b_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_n \geq |b_n|.
$$

(and multiplicity is one.) One can prove this using Weyl character formula (e.g. see [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/lingxiao/assets/honors_thesis.pdf)).

Kirillov's [orbit method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_method) gives connections between irreducible representations of Lie groups and coadjoint orbits (i.e. orbits $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathfrak{g}^{*}$ stable under the coadjoint action $\mathrm{Ad}^*: G \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g}^{*})$). In case of compact groups, irreducible representations are in bijection with *integral* coadjoint orbits, which is the orbit of highest weight.

My question is:

> can we understand branching phenomena for Lie groups via orbit method, at least for compact groups?

For example, when $G = \mathrm{SO}(3)$ and $H = \mathrm{SO}(2)$ (where $H$ is embedded in $G$ via $h \mapsto \left(\begin{smallmatrix} h & \\ & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$), irreducible representations can be labeled as $\pi_a$ and $\sigma_b$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. By the branching rule, $\sigma_b$ occurs in the decomposition of $\pi_a|_{\mathrm{SO}(2)}$ if and only if $a \geq |b|$.
If we consider the corresponding coadjoint orbits as spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3 \simeq \mathfrak{so}(3)^*$ and integers in $\mathbb{R} \simeq \mathfrak{so}(2)^*$, we "can" interpret branching rule as "integers $b = -a, -a+1, \dots, 0, \dots, a-1, a$ on $x$-axis that lies in & on the sphere of radius $a$", but it seems ad hoc to me and doesn't seem to generalize easily to $\mathrm{SO}(2n+1) \supset \mathrm{SO}(2n)$ or any other Lie groups.
I can't find any references discussing about geometric interpretations of branching problems, so it would be great if someone can provide them or give any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this paper deals with some special cases: https://math.mit.edu/~dav/spheres.pdf

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thank you!